# How to design an electrical system on water?

Tags: electrical-engineering, design

Is there a way to design an electrical system (wires, resistors, batteries etc.) on the surface of water so that it doesn't sink, receives heat from water and doesn't deteriorate because of water getting there(is waterproof)? I think of a floating heat conductive platform close to water, but I am not a professional so I'm not sure. Could you help, please?

Comment: think about an aluminum fishing boat

Comment: Or even a piece of plastic floating in the garbage patch. Property that allows floating can be thought of as weight vs weight of water displaced.

Comment: @Abel thank you! I already used vynil as a heat conductive water insulator and foam plastic to not let everything sink; it worked pretty well too :D

Comment: What are you doing exactly. You might loose a little power, but water isn't a problem if the conductors conduct better than water. Pure water is a lousy conductor. Sea water is better, but not great. Toasters don't work very well under water, but you can probably run an old radio under water. You just have to increase the component spacing a little bit to account for the lower dielectric constant., and the efficiency will be lower. Maintain a voltage that prevents corrosion on all components - no galvanic corrosion. Don't let conductive thingies (life) swim around and disrupt things.

Comment: https://nemopowertools.com/product/nemo-angle-grinder-50m-v2/

Comment: But a more practical method is to run the electric circuit in transformer oil and let the oil heat sink with the water.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I don't see any reason why this would not be possible. You are basically describing a boat with a lower hull-temperature than the water it is in.

Maybe you can elaborate on what your goal is with this platform? Then we can probably give a better answer to its feasibility.

Comment: This is better suited as a comment.

Comment: Yes, I need to place a bunch of thermoelements with heat sinks as close to the surface water as possible. My problem is I don't know how to make it so that they don't sink, still get heated by the water below them and the whole system is waterproof at the same time

Comment: @AJN I guess you're right. Unfortunately, I cannot comment yet :(

Comment: @zuzelle It's definitely possible. Ideally you would prevent having any electrical elements in direct contact with the water. Maybe you could add heat sinks/conductors to the bottom of your thermoelements that connect with the water, so that the elements don't need to be directly in the water.

Comment: Okay, thank you

Comment: By the way, do you know any (light weight?) material which is waterproof and heat conductive at the same time to cover the elements? Because heat sinks need to be on the top

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).